# If there are perpendicular diagonals in a trapezoid, will it be a normal trapezoid or an isoceles trapezoid?

Tags: geometry

will the trapezoid be forced to be an isosceles or can it be a normal trapezoid but with perpendicular diagonals?

Comment: draw some pictures. Start with two perpendicular lines which will be (contain) the diagonals, then draw two parallel segments ending on them to serve as the parallel edges of the trapezoid. Just do it.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)